# What is the 'char' keyword used for?

Tags: javascript, char, keyword

What is the `char` reserved keyword used for in JavaScript (as type declaration is not necessary), and especially, what is the correct syntax to use it (could someone give me a proper full example)?

Because writing  `char c;` throws an interpretation error saying `missing ; before statement`, just before the `c`?

Comment: The error you get when doing `char c` is not unexpected. Try `blah c` and you will get a similar error. While your question does actually have a historical context in this case (which is what makes it interesting), I don't think it's the cause of the error you get.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a lot of reserved keyword in JavaScript that are reserved for "future" use. They don't necessarily have a current use and a description.

MDN does list some of them that have this special "future use" status here  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words (thanks to [DCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233508/dcoder)) and you can also read from that article :

> The following are reserved as future keywords by the ECMAScript specification.  They have no special functionality at present, but they might at some future time, so they cannot be used as identifiers. These keywords may not be used in either strict or non-strict mode.

To expand a little further as to why it's consider a reserved keyword in some places and in some places it's not. The ECMAScript v3 specification did include `char` as a reserved keyword, but the ECMAScript v5  specification (which is starting to be the most common one) does not include it.

Comment: A link to the list of said reserved words can't hurt. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: I feel the need to note that not all engines will actually care about using char. Offhand, I see v8, JägerMonkey, and Carakan don't complain at all when you run something like `var char = 5;`, so they don't really treat it as a reserved word. The huge list of "future-reserved-words" from Java was thrown out in ECMAScript 5, so I have a feeling IE (especially IE6/IE7) may complain about `var char = 5`, though I don't have a copy of it on this computer to test it.

Comment: Ok, so as far as I understand it, my notepad++ editor did recognize the char keyword, but firefox 11 and HTML 5 do not, so they act as if they did not know the word, like Reid said. So if it won't be any use, I will let go of that problem then, and keep learning what works...

Comment: Note that `char` will raise an error in the Google Closure Compiler.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

Also as @HoLyVieR pointed out and shown in comments below, `char` keyword is reserved for future use. [See this link for more information](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Reserved_Words) (Thanks to @djmadscribbler) .

---

[There is no reserved keyword `char` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), you must be confusing it with [reserved keyword `char` of Java instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

Comment: ECMAScript 3 reserved all of the Java reserved words, and not every browser has yet implemented the ECMAScript 5 standard as JavaScript.

Comment: Actually there is http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Reserved_Words HoLyVieR has it right - it's not actively being used now but it is reserved for future use

Comment: @djmadscribbler: Thanks for that link. Updated the answer with details :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the ECMAscript documentation ( http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf section 
7.6.1 ) char isn't a reserved word at all.

I'm guessing if you're seeing that as a reserved word somewhere then it's a specific implementation.

http://jsfiddle.net/BCruP/

Edit: Above reference was EMCAscript 5.

EMCAScript 3 ( http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf ) documentation lists char as a future reserved word, however, EMCAScript 5 seems to have dropped that off the list.