# SyntaxError: missing variable name

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm running [JavaScript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/) on a project to check for common programming errors. I'm hitting this error:

> **SyntaxError:** missing variable name

On this line:

```
var char, font;
```

From Googling, I've found that that error is shown when a reserved word is used as a variable name; but judging by [MDN's list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), neither `char` nor `font` is reserved.

What is the problem here?

Comment: jslint.com doesn't report an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer by reading [What is the 'char' keyword used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046439/what-is-the-char-keyword-in-javascript).

Apparently `char` was reserved in ECMA 3, but removed as a reserved keyword in ECMA 5.

I've renamed my `var` now, to prevent any potential issues arising with old implementations.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if the error was clearer. Perhaps something as intuitive as "`X` Reserved word tried to be declared as variable". I mean, JS interpreters know which blinking word is the issue, right!

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

`char` is a keyword reserved by JavaScript.

I think `font` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

As this question gets returned on the first page of a google search for `JS Missing variable name`, and I feel it is the most appropriate out of the other SO questions which mention this error, am going to detail another reason for this error here:

> When using bookmarklet code that has **%20** HTMLEntity's in place of **spaces**, in (for example) Firefox's Scratchpad.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making these changes to my code.

I had:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2;
```

I changed it to this (by mistake), which cause the error:

```
var a = 1,
var b = 2;
```

I resolved it with this:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
```